# Joomla website error

Tags: php, joomla3.0

Cant access to my joomla site anymore. I have the following error

Can't open D:\Sites\puissance.co\public_html/web.config.txt for reading: No such file or directory  at D:\Sites\puissance.co\public_html\setup_script.cgi line 184, <DATA> line 4.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that "D:\Sites\puissance.co\public_html/web.config.txt" does not exist.

And the reason is that your slash is backwards.

```
D:\Sites\puissance.co\public_html\web.config.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have any idea how to change the slash back to normal? I did not change any back end file and the site was working fine just couple of hours ago.

Comment: Considering it's a CGI file, it probably is not plain text.  Which means that that particular entry is populated from somewhere else, and probably cannot be changed in a text editor.  You'll need to find the control panel where there is a reference to "/web.config.txt" and fix it there.

Comment: I did change it, but it is not working. I still have the same error

Comment: Then the file must really be missing.  All the setups I see for this are at the server level, and all of them are Linux.  That path you have is Windows.  What kind of server are you using?

Comment: I am using a windows server

Comment: okay, then.  Are you sure that file is really there, at that path?

Comment: yes I am positive. Maybe i can backup up the site, delete all files and install them back.

Comment: On my other joomla website I have both web.config.txt and web.config files in my directory root and it works fine. But whenever I reload the url page in the new site i am working now, the web.config.txt file is automatically removed from the directory.

Comment: Thanks I got it fixed. Needed to upload both files using ftp server.